# Bash trim some of the text

Tags: unix-text-processing

I have an output that looks like this

```
root@machine:path# someapp report | grep Lost
    Lost Workers: 0
```

How can I grep only the digit at the end?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
someapp report | grep -i lost | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

Run app, pipe STDOUT through tr to remove runs of spaces, cut the new string using a space and then select the 4th field

test:

```
echo "    Lost Workers: 0" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine search and parse with sed:

```sh
echo '    Lost Workers: 0' | sed -n '/Lost/ s/.*[[:blank:]]//p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines that look like `grep | cut ...` or `grep | tr | cut` or similar are almost always better off using `awk`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nLost Workers: 0\nbar\n' | awk '/Lost/{print $NF}'
0
```